# in spring mvc, is it possible to specify an url for a given View at runtime?

Tags: spring-mvc

in spring mvc, is it possible to specify an url for a given View at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding of Spring MVC this question doesn't not quite compute. A URL maps to a controller more than to a view. And from that controller you can render any view you like, making the decision at runtime. Plus you can certainly at runtime redirect the browser to any URL. In addition you can use expressions to map multiple URLs to a single controller. Does that help or would you like to rephrase the question?

Comment: I think redirecting is the only way to do that. Thanks.